# visual studio 2010 express STL list compiler error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, stl

I am porting some code from linux to windows and am coming up with some strange error.  I have the following class:

(header)
RegionRectangle.h

```
#ifndef __RECTANGLE_H__
#define __RECTANGLE_H__
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Rectangle
{
public:
    Rectangle(int x = 0,int y = 0,int width = 0,int height = 0, int threshold=0);
    int x();
    int y();
    int width();
    int height();
    void x(int);
    void y(int);
    void width(int);
    void height(int);
    void threshold(int);
    int threshold(void);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, const Rectangle& r);
private:
    int _x;
    int _y;
    int _width;
    int _height;
    int _threshold;
};

#endif
```

(implementation)

RegionRectangle.cpp

```
#include "RegionRectangle.h"

Rectangle::Rectangle(int myx,int myy, int mywidth, int myheight,int threshold)
{
    _x=myx;
    _y=myy;
    _width=mywidth;
    _height=myheight;
    _threshold=threshold;
}
int Rectangle::x(void)
{
    return _x;
}
int Rectangle::y(void)
{
    return _y;
}
int Rectangle::width(void)
{
    return _width;
}
int Rectangle::height(void)
{
    return _height;
}

void Rectangle::x(int x)
{
    _x=x;
}

void Rectangle::y(int y)
{
    _y=y;
}

void Rectangle::width(int width)
{
   _width=width;
}

void Rectangle::height(int height)
{
    _height=height;
}
void Rectangle::threshold(int thresh)
{
    _threshold=thresh;
}
int Rectangle::threshold(void)
{
    return _threshold;
}

ostream& operator&lt;&lt;(ostream& output, const Rectangle& p)
{
    output << "[ (" << p._x << "," << p._y << "," << p._width << "," << p._height << "), threshold: " << p._threshold << " ]";
    return output;
}
```

I have another header file that has a function as such:

```
bool hasKey( map<PageNumberSide, list<Rectangle> > myMap, PageNumberSide myKey);
```

The error messages I'm getting are these:

```
enter code here
```

This third referencing file does include RegionRectangle.h  any ideas why this would not work?

```
1>  Utils.cpp
1>c:\documents and settings\ferru001\my documents\work\cira_svn\win32_cira\Utils.h(56): error C2923: 'std::list' : 'Rectangle' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Ty'
1>          C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\wingdi.h(3989) : see declaration of 'Rectangle'
1>c:\documents and settings\ferru001\my documents\work\cira_svn\win32_cira\Utils.h(60): error C2923: 'std::list' : 'Rectangle' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Ty'
1>          C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\wingdi.h(3989) : see declaration of 'Rectangle'
```

Comment: Please format your code correctly, rather than trying to use HTML markup (which doesn't work here). Specifically, use the "0101" button on the toolbar to mark code as code, and do _not_ quote `<` and `>` as `&lt;` and `&gt;`.

Comment: also what is the compiler error?

Comment: 1>  Utils.cpp
1>c:\documents and settings\ferru001\my documents\work\cira_svn\win32_cira\Utils.h(56): error C2923: 'std::list' : 'Rectangle' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Ty'
1>          C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\wingdi.h(3989) : see declaration of 'Rectangle'
1>c:\documents and settings\ferru001\my documents\work\cira_svn\win32_cira\Utils.h(60): error C2923: 'std::list' : 'Rectangle' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Ty'

Comment: you can edit your question to include that text FYI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is:

> C:\Program Files\**Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\wingdi.h**(3989)
>   : see declaration of 'Rectangle'

The compiler thinks you're referring to the Win32 SDK Rectangle function in wingdi.h, not the one you just defined. I suggest renaming your rectangle (or putting in a namespace) and seeing what happens.

Comment: Thank you very much, I obviously did not look closely enough at the error messages... been at work for 12 hours :)
Thank you very much for your help